# I need some explanation about ?, &, /, <, > xss protection

Tags: xss

https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-PYTHON-DJANGO-2389002

This website tells that replacing  `?, &, /, <, >`

Convert special characters such as  `?, &, /, <, >` and spaces to their respective HTML or URL encoded equivalents.

Good to protect Xss.

i know about `<` and `>` can any one elaborate why `?, &` and `/`.

how these 3 could harm it (only with these 3  `?, &, /`)

Answer (score 0):

The site says (emphasis mine)

> Convert special characters such as `?`, `&`, `/`, `<`, `>` and spaces to their respective HTML **or URL encoded equivalents**.

So this is talking not just about HTML but about URLs. And a question mark or an ampersand in a URL query can do a *lot* of damage. You may have *intended* that the url `f"http://example.com/accounts/{account_id}/"` allow a user to see their account summary, but it turns out that my `account_id` is `admin/console?username=admin&session=...`. Funny that, it turns out my account has access to everything on your website.

More broadly, if you're going to embed user data in URLs, HTML, or **anything**, being a bit overly-cautious can pay off.

First, you should **never**, let me repeat that: **NEVER**,  be sanitizing your own inputs for malicious XSS code unless you're a cybersecurity expert. That neat little trick you thought of five minutes ago in the shower, I promise there are cryptanalysts who know how to get around it ten times over already. There are sanitization libraries out there that can do it a hundred times better than you, simply because that's the whole point of them and because they're written by leading crypto experts.

Second, if you, for some reason, fell asleep during that last paragraph and didn't notice the all-caps "**NEVER**" I left for you, and you decide to roll your own sanitization, you should be overzealous. If there's a *possibility* that `&` causes a problem in HTML, then turn it into `&amp;`. Unconditionally. Don't labor over whether or not it will, it's possible and there's an easy fix. Save yourself the heartache down the road.

Comment: I think I understand a little bit of what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: Wao where did you learn this all.?